# AWS Network Firewall + Windows EC2 Instance - google.com is not blocked in browser but is blocked in the command line

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, firewall

I'm using AWS Network Firewall along with a Windows EC2 instance to test. The goal is to allow access to only allowed URLs, which are:

```
example.com
.amazon.com
.amazonaws.com
```

This generally works. Sites like yahoo, reddit, netflix etc are blocked and show up in the alert logs. However, google.com doesn't get blocked from the browser. It only gets blocked from the command line when using curl.

Sequence of events:

```
1. Open browser
2. Go to google.com -> The site loads without an issue
3. There isn't any entry in the alerts log
4. Open the network tab in the browser and copy the cURL related to google.com
5. Open command prompt
6. Run the cURL command. This is blocked.
7. Check the alerts log. An entry alerting for google.com is present.
```

My Firewall Policy has the following rules:

1. Stateless Rule Groups

   a. allow-rdp: allows RDP connections from any source to any destination. Action is "pass". I use this otherwise I've issues with logging in using AWS Fleet Manager.
2. Stateful Rule Groups

   a. allowlist: allows specific URLs via HTTPS. List includes example.com, .amazon.com, and .amazonaws.com

My network architecture is similar to the last image [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/network-firewall/latest/developerguide/arch-single-zone-igw.html) with both the firewall subnet and the customer subnet being public subnets (the route tables are as shown in the link).

Answer (score 1):

It is more likely use of Encrypted Client Hello (ECH, formerly ESNI) with Server Name Indication (SNI) evasion.

The AWS Network Firewall only looks at the client-settable TLS SNI (comparable to the HTTP Host header) when deciding to block or allow traffic. A trivial example of getting around it is to just set it explicitly in the curl command line:

`curl -kv --connect-to "example.com:443:8.8.8.8:443" -H "Host: 8.8.8.8" https://example.com/`

That command would punch through the AWS firewall and connect to a Google-owned IP address even if only `example.com` were allowed.

An alternate way, and this bypass, is explored deeper in the [AWS Network Firewall egress filtering can be easily bypassed](https://canglad.com/blog/2023/aws-network-firewall-egress-filtering-can-be-easily-bypassed/) blog post.

The ECH evasion is an obfuscation mechanism explicitly designed to bypass SNI-based firewalls. It may be beyond the scope here to delve into greater detail but, essentially, it encrypts the intended SNI in an *inner* field and leaves out the original *outer* SNI field for creative use.

The blog post [Disabling Encrypted ClientHello in Google Chrome, and Why](https://chasersystems.com/blog/disabling-encrypted-clienthello-in-google-chrome-and-why/) goes into further detail along with instructions on disabling it in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the fact that google uses QUIC and not always TLS. AWS Network Firewall has a limitation when inspecting TLS.

> TLS inspection of UDP-based transport protocols such as Quick UDP Internet Connections (QUIC) isn't supported. You can configure your applications so that they don't switch from TCP to UDP-based transport protocols. If you want to prevent TLS traffic from using the QUIC protocol, modify your application to deny traffic using QUIC or create a firewall stateful rule to block QUIC traffic.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/network-firewall/latest/developerguide/tls-inspection-considerations.html

You would need a different rule to address that:

```
drop udp $HOME_NET any -> any 443 (msg:"Block QUIC traffic"; sid:1000001;)
```

Comment: In addition some browsers use DNS Over HTTPS, which means a DNS level block can't work...